# image upload in a template

Tags: django, templates, django-forms

My issue is if I upload from admin an image it works fine but if I want to add an image from my template, it seems that my image does not updload.
It is weird as in the request.Post form, path of my image is present.

I've no message of error...

this is my model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title',max_length=64, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField('Descritpion', blank=False)
    Creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    enddate= models.DateField('Ending Date', blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category")
    initialBid = models.DecimalField('Bid', max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    photo = ResizedImageField(size=[300, 150], upload_to='images/', default='images/default.jpg')
    active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} : {self.title} {self.initialBid} {self.Creation_date}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Check how the current ending date is after created date,
        d1 = self.Creation_date
        d2 = self.enddate
        if d2 <= d1:
            raise ValueError("End date must be a day after today")
        super(Listing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my form:

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    enddate = forms.DateField(label='Date of auction End', widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'),
                                 input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self._newly_created = kwargs.get('instance') is None
        self.Creation_date = datetime.now()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('title','description','enddate','category','initialBid','photo','active')
```

my template:

```
<h2>{% if not form.instance.pk %}Create listing {% else %} Edit {% endif %}</h2>
    <form id="create-edit-client" class="form-horizontal"  action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}

        {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}

            <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
            {{ form.category|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
            {{ form.initialBid|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                {{ form.enddate|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
            {{ form.active|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>

        </div>
    <br>
        {{ form.photo|as_crispy_field }}
            <br>
            <br>

    </form>
```

in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# gestion ds media
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ......
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views:

```
@login_required
def editlisting(request, listing_id):
    obj = Listing.objects.filter(pk=listing_id).first()
    if obj is None:
        return render(request, "errors/404.html", {
            "entryTitle": listing_id
        })
    else:
        form = NewListingForm(instance=Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id))
        modification=True # used in template to check if modification are allowed
        # read only form if not author
        user = request.user.id
        if obj.author.id != user:
            modification=False

        # manage save
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = NewListingForm(request.POST, instance=Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id))

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'listing saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

        # check if in wishes on get
        wishbool=False
        wish = Wishing.objects.filter(item=listing_id, follower=request.user.id).first()
        if wish is not None:
            wishbool = True

        return render(request, 'auctions/newListing.html', {
            "form": form,
            "existing": True,
            'title': "Edit Listing",
            "wishing": wishbool,
            "modification":modification
        })
```

thanks for help

Comment: Show me your views please

Comment: add it at the end of my message. sorry to forget that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form = NewListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id))
```

Comment: Not Found: /media/JPEG_example_flower.jpg
[25/Sep/2020 18:17:47] "GET /media/JPEG_example_flower.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1836

Comment: it does not pass: if form.is_valid(): other fields are ok it ays that photo field is required... but this is where I try to upload a picture

Comment: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: print request.FILES ...what are you getting from it?

Comment: print : <MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: photo field is it <input type=file> ?

Comment: in my template : {{ form.photo|as_crispy_field }}

Comment: in model : photo = ResizedImageField(size=[300, 150], upload_to='images/', default='images/default.jpg')

Comment: in my form: comes directly from model

Comment: check in Desktop , inspect elements

Comment: it works on my create form and it is same template used. Seems not working when I edit

Comment: <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" class="clearablefileinput" id="id_photo">

Comment: its ok.
can access your desktop remotely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222086/discussion-between-philippe-haumesser-and-surya-pratap-rana).

Answer (score 0):

for getting the images or files you need pass another request that it's called request.FILES, so:

```
@login_required
def editlisting(request, listing_id):
    obj = Listing.objects.filter(pk=listing_id).first()
    if obj is None:
        return render(request, "errors/404.html", {
            "entryTitle": listing_id
        })
    else:
        form = NewListingForm(instance=Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id))
        modification=True # used in template to check if modification are 
        allowed
        # read only form if not author
        user = request.user.id
        if obj.author.id != user:
            modification=False

        # manage save
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = NewListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
instance=Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id))

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'listing saved')  # message for 
inform user of success - See messages in html file
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

        # check if in wishes on get
        wishbool=False
        wish = Wishing.objects.filter(item=listing_id, 
follower=request.user.id).first()
        if wish is not None:
            wishbool = True

        return render(request, 'auctions/newListing.html', {
            "form": form,
            "existing": True,
            'title': "Edit Listing",
            "wishing": wishbool,
            "modification":modification
           })
```